# MediaElement is repeating clips automatically, and sometimes fails to play them

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I have an app which plays a few short sound clips. To play them I simply set the source to the new clip path, which is a WMA I encoded with Expression Encoder using WP7 settings. It's not even worth sharing the code -- there's an event handler. In it, I set the ME.Source property to a new Uri. It's set to AutoPlay, so that's it! Here:

```
    private void PlaySound(ItemViewModel sound) {
        Model.CurrentSound = sound;
        CurrentSound.Source = new Uri(sound.Path, UriKind.Relative);
    }

    private void Sounds_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        var list = ((ListBox) sender);
        var item = (ItemViewModel) list.SelectedItem;
        SelectItem(item);
    }
```

Also I should point out that the sounds are all resources (build type = Resource). I need them to be because the app needs to discover them dynamically. The paths are all like this, "sounds/foo/bar/sound.wma". Sometimes there is a space in the path, it is url encoded with %20 (this is how the resource manager returns the path, I didn't do that).

The problem is many people, but not all, are saying that the sound auto-repeats. The sounds are very short, only a few seconds, so it's very annoying. I don't understand how this is happening, the MediaElement doesn't even have an auto repeat feature.

Perhaps related, but some have also complained that every now and then the sound does not play. They have to click it again. All I can think of is that there is something wrong with how the sounds are encoded, but they are WMA, and as I said, I encoded them using the 'playback in WP7' settings in expression encoder. How could it be that it works usually but not other times if that were the case, anyway?

I'm at a loss and my app is getting some bad reviews because of this behavior. Help!

Comment: Clearly something really odd is happening, in that case how sure are you that "its not event worth sharing the code" is a good assessment of things?

Comment: Fair enough :) I added the code and some more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with repeating turned out to be needing to do this:

```
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = false;
```

I think what happened was the user would be in another app that sets this to true, and upon opening my app that value was still true! That has to be a bug, it's totally unexpected. If you look at other sound-playing apps like soundboard apps, there are users complaining in the reviews about the very same thing.. "I wish it wouldn't repeat the sounds..."

Comment: I hate to accept my own answer but this was it. @AnthonyWJones answer was helpful but the failing problem was a red herring, I only brought it up because I thought it might be related to the repeating problem, it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

"there's and event handler" but you don't say of what? It could be that event firing over and over or not at all in some cases.  Potentially your code has a logical errors where you have failed to detach an existing handler and then added another.  As usage progresses you end up with a single event being handled by multiple handlers.

**Edit**

The Selection changed event is notorious for firing more frequently than we'd like.  I suggest you add some debounce code that makes record of the last item selected and how long ago.  If the next selected item is the same as the last one and it was say less than a second ago then swallow the event without doing anything else.

Comment: Wow that's unexpected. Is that unreliable behavior documented? This must be the problem, I'll try to guard against refirings. I think just seeing if the sound is the same as the last one will work for my scenario instead of a timing mechanism.

Comment: Any idea why the ME will _sometimes_ fail to load the sound? I'm still having the other problem I mentioned. Even after adding code to ensure the same sound won't play twice in a row, it simply fails. The MediaFailed event fires. The very same sound works if I go to a different sound and then back to it again. This is in the emulator, but my users have reported the same thing. Very frustrating... I thought of putting code in MediaFailed that makes it retry, but what a hack, it'd probably cause me other problems. All these sounds are resources and all play successfully most of the time.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop:  Since you've been able to reproduce and you get a media failed event the next step is to examine the exception exposed by the `Exception` property of the event args in the `MediaFailed` event.

Comment: MediaFailed never provides any details -- from what I read, it's purposefully generic. The args to the event has an ErrorException property, which only has the message "AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR". There's no other information at all on the exception. No stack trace, no nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to play Sound Effects - in which case you might be better off using the XNA SoundEffect mechanism

e.g. http://www.japf.fr/2010/08/sound-effect-in-wp7-sl-application/

SoundEffect only works for WAV files (PCM) - but I've used it in several apps and scripts including embedded content files and downloaded files (e.g. [translation](http://www.wp7comp.com/translate-a-bull-get-multilingual-get-bovine/) and [ironruby scripts](http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/ByTag?tag=music)).

The XNA class works well within SL and allows multiple sound effects to be played at the same time.

Comment: I considered that, problem is I specifically want to only play 1 sound at a time. Also, the UI has a play/pause button, and I don't see how you can know when the sound has stopped playing with SoundEffect. Is there a more sophisticated way of playing sound that gives you more control over it in XNA that you can use from Silverlight?

Comment: Not done this myself, but I think you can create and track `SoundEffectInstance` instances - these have state telling you if they are `Playing` or `Stopped` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.state.aspx

Comment: Thanks... hmm, no events that I can see, which would require I create a timer to poll the state. Yuck.. Makes sense in a game that has a game loop, but this is a very simple SL app.

Comment: there's always CompositionTarget.Rendering if you want a really tight loop (ahem, sorry, I'm supposed to be giving nice advice, not hacky stuff...)